# Kendo UI Bar charts to read from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, kendo-ui

I was wondering if anyone has any examples or links for Kendo UI Bar Charts reading data from SQL Server? The sample that I downloaded from Kendo UI Demos website does not have this feature, and I need to look at some examples to develop my own application. I am very new to this and would appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: Are you familiar with returning JSON from the server?  Where would you like to start in the learning process?  The very beginning?

Comment: My knowledge about JSON is about a week old. All I know about JSON is that it is something similar to XML data. But I dont know how to generate or consume JSON data.I work with databases most of the time and this is the first time I am working with a UI product. Just the learning curve!

Comment: Hello @rvphx , I am learning KendoUI and I just have the same question as you did. If you found any example or answer, can you please share it with me?

Comment: This dates back to February as you can see. All I remember is that I used the MVC method to pull data from SQL Server and then display it on my application. I did not continue with the project as it was something beyond my skill set.

Comment: I would still suggest you to look at the Kendo UI website and follow the samples over there. Thats the best information so far that I could get and refer for my issues.